# Bind GUI element property to boolean expression - WPF GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to bind a button's `IsEnabled` to the result of a boolean expression.

I only find quite complex solutions using converters or other methods. Is it also possible in a more simple way?

**Example code:**

```xml
<Button IsEnabled="{ Binding Path=IsRecordingEnabled }" />
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool IsRecording { get; set; } = false;
    public string LoggingFolder { get; set; } = null;

    public bool IsRecordingEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return !IsRecording && LoggingFolder != null;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Obviously the Button is not updating when the expression changes. I understand that I need to notify the GUI via `OnNotifyPropertyChanged` or similar. But how to do that in my case where I want to handle the boolean expression which has no `set` method but is changed via the composition of `IsRecording` and `LoggingFolder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to invoke the `PropertyChanged` event when you change either `IsRecording` or `ReplayLogFile`. In the event args, you have to tell that the property `IsRecordingEnabled` changed:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isRecording = false;;
    public bool IsRecording
    {
     get => _isRecording;
     set
     {
         _isRecording = value;
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsRecordingEnabled)));
     }

    private string _replayLogFile = null;
    public string ReplayLogFile
    {
       get => _replayLogFile;
       set
       {
           _replayLogFile = value;
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsRecordingEnabled)));
       }
    }

    public bool IsRecordingEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return !IsRecording && LoggingFolder != null;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I'm using a mixture of this answer and MindSwipe's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [de-facto default implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) of `PropertyChanged` is:

```cs
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

You can see it has the parameter `name` decorated with the attribute `[CallerMemberName]` it "Allows you to obtain the method or property name of the caller to the method." ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netcore-3.1)). Which means that you can manually specify which property changed by passing in the name. This means you can tell the GUI a property changed, without having to have a setter and set it. Like so:

```cs
private bool _isRecording = false;

public bool IsRecording
{
    get => _isRecording;
    set
    {
        _isRecording = value;
   
        // You could omit the next line, if the UI doesn't bind to this property
        OnPropertyChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRecordingEnabled));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ToggleButton instead of a button.

WPF:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="record" Content="Record" .../>
```

In Main Window you can use:
record.IsChecked = true/false; to set or reset the state of the ToggleButton

```
if (record.IsChecked == true && LoggingFolder == null)
{
    //Do what you want
}
```

You can also use a click event

```
private void record_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoggingFolder != null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding `ToggleButton`. A perfect improvement for my use-case. However updating the GUI, I want to use a 'declarative' approach instead of the 'imparative' u're suggesting.